# Structuring Selenium RC within a two-war project?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-rc, jenkins

I have a project which needs to deploy multiple wars on a tomcat instance. My first thought for structuring selenium is to create a downstream `jenkins` build that runs selenium tests against some fixed selenium server, which is pushed with new wars when any of the two war projects build.

Within the jenkins ecosystem, what's the best way to run through a series of selenium tests with the selenium test runner on a remote machine? Given lack of resources, it might be easiest if the selenium test runner exists on the selenium test server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins can be configured to build multiple projects at once. What you could do is have a super build poll SCM for all projects, push them to the functional (selenium) test server, then run selenium tests from some main project or an independent project on its own, using whatever runner method you prefer.

`Track another repository url`

and

`Add Build Step`

will be your two most used tools here.